# Grafana bar chart

Tags: bar-chart, visualization, grafana

I am trying to create a bar chart on grafana in which it shows latency for two categories from a field which I query from the db. There are total three fields an hour field, category and an aggregate calculation. Basically I want hour field on X-axis and two bars to show aggregation for each category and aggregate field on Y-axis.

Currently it looks like this:

In the image below those marked in Red are the two categories. Lets say A,B. The latency is my aggregation marked in blue and the green mark is hour.

[image]

Basically, I want to achieve something like below image: Category A,B on x-axis wrt hour, and latency on y-axis.

[image]

This is my query:

```
select * from (
  select   extract(hour from event_datetime) Hour, category, (source_timedelta_s_ + pipeline_timedelta_s_) Latency from <table>
  where extract(date from event_datetime) = '2022-12-13' and  extract(hour from event_datetime) > 12
)
PIVOT (
   avg(Latency)
   FOR category IN ('A','B')
) t
order by t.Hour
```

Your help will be appreciated thanks. Sorry If my explanation is confusing.